# How can I define an environment similar to alignat, but calculates the number of columns automatically like align?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align, environments, alignat

I've read several posts explaining the difference between `align` and `alignat` such as [this TeX SE answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200844/228055)
I want to make a new environment with the capabilities of `align` (create as many as desired based on the environment's content without having to input a `<number>` argument) but with the "no horizontal spaces" property of `alignat`.

Is this possible? If so how can I define such an environment, (let's say `altalign`)?

Thank you.

Comment: isn't that exactly the question answered in the post that you link to?

Comment: Related [Why the alignat environment in amsmath needs a mandatory argument? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637394/why-the-alignat-environment-in-amsmath-needs-a-mandatory-argument) (i.e. yes it's possible.)

Comment: Look like you can just pass 99 in and get what you want. [Caveats of useing \begin{alignat*}{99} - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274448/caveats-of-useing-beginalignat99?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Someone also made a "align-with-specified-column-separation" here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40126/250119

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is to make a new environment that forwards `99` to `alignat`: <sub>(remark, this is the "standard" method to redefine environment; nevertheless it will not work for some particular environments that hard codes the environment name. Fortunately it works with this one)</sub>

```
\newenvironment{alignatz}{\alignat{99}}{\endalignat}

\catcode`*=11
\newenvironment{alignatz*}{\alignat*{99}}{\endalignat*}
\catcode`*=12
```

Usage:

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\newenvironment{alignatz}{\alignat{99}}{\endalignat}

\catcode`*=11
\newenvironment{alignatz*}{\alignat*{99}}{\endalignat*}
\catcode`*=12

\begin{alignatz}
    a &= b \quad & c &= d \\
    a &= b & c &= d
\end{alignatz}

\begin{alignatz*}
    a &= b \quad & c &= d \\
    a &= b & c &= d
\end{alignatz*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Change the environment name yourself. Sometimes people here name custom commands/environments by the asker's name, but I don't like doing that